# ModelForm not saving data

Tags: django

It is not saving up the data:

```
# Models

class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()

# Forms   

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment

#Views.py

def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save()
            save_it.save()
            comment = form.cleaned_data["body"]
        return render(request, 'task-result.html', {
        'form': form, 'comment': comment,
        })
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'Task-form.html', {
        'form': form,
        })
```

AS you may see, I am not only trying to save comment's data to database but also and print it comment out. So where is my mistake?

Comment: Is the form valid? And why the double save? The second one looks like an error to me.

Comment: Yes the form is valid. Where you see double save?

Comment: `save_it = form.save()`
`save_it.save()`

Comment: You say it is not saving to database, is it printint the comment int he template fine ?

Comment: Can you please show also you template? And for sure there shouldn't be 2 saves as @Germano said.